# Loop through included files in php

Tags: php

I have this code snippet here:

```
<?php
include('a.php');
include('b.php');
include('c.php');
include('d.php');
include('e.php');
?>
```

I would like to have a loop run through this file and execute each of these files once. How can i go about this? I am new to php.

Comment: Why cannot you include all of them at once?

Comment: Am sorry but i dont get what you mean.

Comment: I mean what is the problem in adding all these file at once?

Comment: Well the thing is i have different queries in the files labelled a, b c , d and e. Each of these queries is executed differently and one at a time. When the query is done, the results are exported to excel and the file is downloaded. I would like to have this done within one file such that when the file is executed, then the queries are run in a loop rather than doing it one at a time which takes long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this...

```
<pre>
<?php 
set_time_limit (0);
$files = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e',);
foreach($files as $f){
    include_once $f.".php";
    echo "finished file $f\n";
    flush();
}
?>
</pre>
```

Comment: Well the thing is i have different queries in the files labelled a, b c , d and e. Each of these queries is executed differently and one at a time. When the query is done, the results are exported to excel and the file is downloaded. I would like to have this done within one file such that when the file is executed, then the queries are run in a loop rather than doing it one at a time which takes long

Comment: Do you mean run in parallel instead of loop?

Comment: And by the way the solution you have given me returns this error:
PHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening 'aphp' for inclusion
Its like the  "." is not recognised or something. And yes i would like them to run in parallel if its better.

Comment: I dont think that parallel will do any good, unless it's on different databases.

Comment: No its on the same database. If this wont do any good then how can i go about the problem i have because now currently with the loop here, it executes only the first file and then stops. It doesnt proceed to execute b, c, d and e

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23747/discussion-between-danilo-kobold-and-roykasa)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
class Loader
{
   protected $files = array();

   public function __construct($files)
   {
       $this->files = $files;
   }
   public function Init()
   {
      foreach($this->files as $file)
      {
          if(file_exists($file)) 
          {
             require_once($file);
          }
      }
}

$loader = new Loader(array("a.php", "b.php","c.php","d.php"));

$loader->init();
```

Wherever your file is located (let's assumed the file that requires all of the files listed in your question is `index.php`).

You're going to want to `require`, or `include` this file (`Loader.php`) in your `index.php` file. For example:

***index.php***

```
<?php
 // file index.php
  require_once('Loader.php');

  $loader = new Loader(array("a.php", "b.php","c.php","d.php"));

  $loader->init();

?>
```

With this setup, your `index.php` file will be able to create objects, and you're code will be much more organized and modular.